# how to draw closed cubic Bezier curve with multiple segments (parametrized)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bezier

[image]In my assignment I tried to create a closed cubic Bezier curve for a roller coaster in python. I use cubic Bezier Formula on my code as mentioned here:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#:~:text=Cubic%20B%C3%A9zier%20curve%20with%20four,that%20can%20be%20scaled%20indefinitely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#:%7E:text=Cubic%20B%C3%A9zier%20curve%20with%20four,that%20can%20be%20scaled%20indefinitely).
I have support points (P0, P3) but not control points (P1, P2) and know that control points should get with linear equations and Gaussian Algorithm, but because can't find a way to implant them as a code, so manipulate the p0, p3 in any segments to make some control points. I know that it's wrong but did that to at least check the other parts of the code. now have a curve that is not similar to my curve that made by exact points implant in a cad application (rhino3d). I want to its because of control points implementation or my visualization has some mistakes.
cheers.[image]
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("C:\\Users\poori\Desktop\support points.txt") as file:
    text = file.read()#.split("Track")[1][4:]

lines = text.split('\n')
non_empty_lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip() != '']
text = ('\n'.join(non_empty_lines))
text_list = text.replace(" ", ",").splitlines()
for i,y in enumerate(text_list):
    text_list[i]=[float(text_list[i].split(",")[0]) , float(text_list[i].split(",")[1]), float(text_list[i].split(",")[2])]

#g = [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(aa_row, bb_col)) for bb_col in zip(*bb)] for aa_row in bb]
s = len(text_list)-1

x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])
z = np.array([])
p1x = np.array([])
p1y = np.array([])
p1z = np.array([])
p2x = np.array([])
p2y = np.array([])
p2z = np.array([])

for i in text_list:
    x = np.append(x, np.array(i[0]))
    y = np.append(y, np.array(i[1]))
    z = np.append(z, np.array(i[2]))

for i in range(len(x)):
    if i == len(x)-1:
        break
    if (i + 2) == len(x):
        p1x = np.append(p1x, np.array((x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[1]) / 6))
        p1y = np.append(p1y, np.array((y[i] + y[i + 1] + y[1]) / 6))
        p1z = np.append(p1z, np.array((z[i] + z[i + 1] + z[1]) / 6))
        p2x = np.append(p2x, np.array((x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[1]) / 3))
        p2y = np.append(p2y, np.array((y[i] + y[i + 1] + y[1]) / 3))
        p2z = np.append(p2z, np.array((z[i] + z[i + 1] + z[1]) / 3))
    else:
        p1x = np.append(p1x, np.array((x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2]) / 6))
        print(x[i])
        p1y = np.append(p1y, np.array((y[i] + y[i + 1] + y[i + 2]) / 6))
        p1z = np.append(p1z, np.array((z[i] + z[i + 1] + z[i + 2]) / 6))
        p2x = np.append(p2x, np.array((x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2]) / 3))
        p2y = np.append(p2y, np.array((y[i] + y[i + 1] + y[i + 2]) / 3))
        p2z = np.append(p2z, np.array((z[i] + z[i + 1] + z[i + 2]) / 3))


s = np.linspace(0, 1, 300, endpoint = False)
Bx = np.array([])
By = np.array([])
Bz = np.array([])

for v in range(len(x)-1):
    for i in s:
        B = (((1-i)**3) * (np.array((x[v],y[v],z[v])))) + (3* ((1-i)**2)* i * (np.array((p1x[v],p1y[v],p1z[v])))) + (3 * (1-i) * (i**2) * (np.array((p2x[v],p2y[v],p2z[v])))) + ((i**3)*(np.array((x[v+1],y[v+1],z[v+1]))))
        Bx = np.append(Bx , B[0])
        By = np.append(By, B[1])
        Bz = np.append(Bz, B[2])


CELLS = 200
nCPTS = np.size(x, 0)
n = nCPTS -1
i = 0
t = np.linspace(0,1, CELLS)
b = []

xBezier = np.zeros((1, CELLS))
yBezier = np.zeros((1, CELLS))
zBezier = np.zeros((1, CELLS))

plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
plt.plot(Bx,By,Bz)#,out[0],out[1])
plt.show()

#support points(needs to find control points by these)
#0, 0, 0
#0,-20.836,0
#0,-38.948,0
#14.277,-38.948,0
#30.064,-38.948,0
#47.36,-38.948,0
#63.942,-38.948,3
#78.327,-38.948,6
#78.327,-30.509,9
#78.327,-22.191,12
#64.542,-22.191,15
#47.662,-22.191,18
#25.768,-22.191,21
#25.768,0.98532,24
#25.768,13.24,27.261
#25.768,23.53,30
#25.768,30.216,33
#42.9,30.216,33
#57.202,30.216,33
#75.909,30.216,33
#75.909,-0.99106,33
#75.909,-2.4834,40
#75.909,-2.6028,49
#76.909,3.2814,53
#77.909,8.2948,53
#78.909,14.468,49
#78.909,14.307,40
#78.909,11.782,33
#78.909,-15.121,36
#60.112,-15.121,39
#43.57,-15.121,42
#27.405,-15.121,48
#15.597,-15.121,48
#15.597,-3.0904,48
#15.597,11.195,48
#15.597,27.638,48
#26.208,27.638,48
#34.6,27.638,48
#34.6,14.052,48
#34.6,3.8624,48
#34.6,-5.5279,45
#44.19,-5.5279,42
#57.776,-5.5279,39
#67.565,-5.5279,33
#67.565,2.9199,27
#67.565,11.511,24
#67.565,19.902,21
#67.565,27.894,18
#67.565,39.226,15
#54.779,39.226,12
#43.924,39.226,9
#30.976,39.226,6
#18.356,39.226,3
#0,39.226,0
#0,17.662,0
#0,0,0
```

Comment: You may need to [rework this post](/help/how-to-ask) a bit, as it's not really clear what you're asking for. Try to describe things in terms of what you set out to do, the code you wrote to do that, what you expected that code to do, what it did instead, and what debugging and (re)searching you've already done to try to solve the problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your comment mike. I`ll  try to make it more clear immediately.

Comment: You might want to use sliders to let the user control the parameters: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html

Comment: @YuliaV thanks for your comment but don't think so that fix the problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you need. If you need to mark some points on your curve, `scatter` could help https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Comment: @YuliaV I attached two pictures of two curves that made by same points. I need to get a smooth curve like the picture of 3d modeling software that i attached above from my code in python with matplotlib or other visualization tools. just compare two pictures of curves that attached.

Comment: Your post suggests that you are given (cubic) Bezier curve sections with just the endpoints (P0 and P3). Theoretically, you can put P1 and P2 where you like in each section and it will produce a smooth curve ... except where it is kinked at successive endpoints. However, the position of P1 will determine the TANGENT at P0 (and similarly P2 for P3). So make sure at least that the tangent direction P1-P0 for one Bezier curve has the same direction as P3-P2 for the preceding one. This should make the tangent continuous as well as the curve itself.

Comment: but if 4points  has same directions. that Bezier curve become to a straight line! does it?

Comment: Do you mean the 4 control points P0, P1, P2, P3 or four successive end points? Either way, if they lie in a straight line then that is a perfectly smooth curve (and there seem to be some examples of it in the rhino3d image).

Comment: i described p0,p1,p2,p3 in the picture above. i can get straight lines, thats not eve need bezier curves. i need bezier curves that along each other and make from them a closed final bezier curve (that in turns, change direction smoothly, but with straight lines its not) .

Comment: Decide the direction of the tangent at each end control point P0 and P3 (e.g. the direction between control points either side). Then situate your P1 and P2 internal points in each section to respect that tangent direction. What you are doing at the moment with P1x,P1y,P1z etc is a bit bizarre.

Comment: @pooriabt, can you supply your file of support points, please. (Edit your question to do so.)

Comment: @lastchance i edit the question and add the points as comments in the end of the code.

Comment: Thanks, I have given some sample code in an answer. I hope it gives you some ideas of a fix.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote earlier in the comments, for a smooth composite Bezier curve you need to ensure that the gradient at the end of each Bezier is continuous.

If - as in your post - you intend to use the given "support points" as the end points of each cubic Bezier (**P0 and P3**) then you need to make an estimate of the tangent direction at those support points here and choose P1 and P2 to match the directions of P1-P0 and P3-P2 to their relevant tangents. (The distances, i.e. lengths of P1-P0 and P3-P2, are not fixed by this requirement. A rough guess is to take them as one third of the straight line distance between end points.) **Note:** there is now what I think is a better approach at the end of this post.

In the code below you can see function smooth() doing that, and setting all of P0, P1, P2, P3 from the support points (aka "knots").

I have hard-coded your support points and also plotted them together with the composite Bezier code. I have turned the plot a little to try and see it from the same view as your CAD; there appears to be one small extra vertical loop - are you sure the support points are exactly the same? Finally, your CAD is not using a composite cubic Bezier curve - it appears to be using what you are calling support points as the actual control points of a higher-order Bezier curve.

Note that I have created a simple Bezier class, to simplify the code.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

############################################################

class Bezier:
    '''class for Cubic Bezier curve'''
    def __init__( self, q0, q1, q2, q3 ):
        self.p0 = np.array( q0 )
        self.p1 = np.array( q1 )
        self.p2 = np.array( q2 )
        self.p3 = np.array( q3 )

    def pt( self, t ):
        return ( 1.0 - t ) ** 3 * self.p0 + 3.0 * t * ( 1.0 - t ) ** 2 * self.p1 + 3.0 * t ** 2 * ( 1.0 - t ) * self.p2 + t ** 3 * self.p3

    def curve( self, n ):
        crv = []
        for t in np.linspace( 0.0, 1.0, n ):
            crv.append( self.pt( t ) )
        return crv

############################################################

def draw3d( BezierData ):
    x = [];   y = [];   z = []
    for B in BezierData:
        arc = Bezier( B[0], B[1], B[2], B[3] )
        for p in arc.curve( 100 ):
            x.append( p[0] )
            y.append( p[1] )
            z.append( p[2] )
    plt.plot( x, y, z )
    
############################################################

def length( vector ): return math.sqrt( np.dot( vector, vector ) )   # find length of a vector (numpy array)

def normalise( vector ): return vector / length( vector )            # normalise a vector (numpy array)

############################################################

def smooth( xyvals ):
    '''Turns list of coordinates into list of Bezier control points by adding intermediate control points'''
    N = len( xyvals )
    result = []

    for i in range( 0, N ):                                          # use tangents to set points P1 and P2
        im, ip, ipp = i - 1, ( i + 1 ) % N, ( i + 2 ) % N            # indices of adjacent points (cyclic)
        if im < 0: im += N
        pm = np.array( xyvals[im] )                                  # earlier point
        p0 = np.array( xyvals[i  ] )                                 # start point of Bezier curve
        p3 = np.array( xyvals[ip ] )                                 # end point of Bezier curve
        p6 = np.array( xyvals[ipp] )                                 # later point
        p1 = p0 + normalise( p3 - pm ) * length( p3 - p0 ) / 3.0     # use tangent at P0 to get P1
        p2 = p3 - normalise( p6 - p0 ) * length( p3 - p0 ) / 3.0     # use tangent at P3 to get P2
        result.append( [ p0, p1, p2, p3 ] )

    return result
    
############################################################

points = [ [0, 0, 0             ], [0,-20.836,0         ], [0,-38.948,0         ], [14.277,-38.948,0    ],
           [30.064,-38.948,0    ], [47.36,-38.948,0     ], [63.942,-38.948,3    ], [78.327,-38.948,6    ],
           [78.327,-30.509,9    ], [78.327,-22.191,12   ], [64.542,-22.191,15   ], [47.662,-22.191,18   ],
           [25.768,-22.191,21   ], [25.768,0.98532,24   ], [25.768,13.24,27.261 ], [25.768,23.53,30     ],
           [25.768,30.216,33    ], [42.9,30.216,33      ], [57.202,30.216,33    ], [75.909,30.216,33    ],
           [75.909,-0.99106,33  ], [75.909,-2.4834,40   ], [75.909,-2.6028,49   ], [76.909,3.2814,53    ],
           [77.909,8.2948,53    ], [78.909,14.468,49    ], [78.909,14.307,40    ], [78.909,11.782,33    ],
           [78.909,-15.121,36   ], [60.112,-15.121,39   ], [43.57,-15.121,42    ], [27.405,-15.121,48   ],
           [15.597,-15.121,48   ], [15.597,-3.0904,48   ], [15.597,11.195,48    ], [15.597,27.638,48    ],
           [26.208,27.638,48    ], [34.6,27.638,48      ], [34.6,14.052,48      ], [34.6,3.8624,48      ],
           [34.6,-5.5279,45     ], [44.19,-5.5279,42    ], [57.776,-5.5279,39   ], [67.565,-5.5279,33   ],
           [67.565,2.9199,27    ], [67.565,11.511,24    ], [67.565,19.902,21    ], [67.565,27.894,18    ],
           [67.565,39.226,15    ], [54.779,39.226,12    ], [43.924,39.226,9     ], [30.976,39.226,6     ],
           [18.356,39.226,3     ], [0,39.226,0          ], [0,17.662,0          ], [0,0,0               ] ]

plt.figure().add_subplot( projection='3d' )

Beziers = smooth( points )                       # create list of Bezier curves from support points
draw3d( Beziers )                                # draw composite Bezier curve

x = [ pt[0] for pt in points ]
y = [ pt[1] for pt in points ]
z = [ pt[2] for pt in points ]
plt.plot( x, y, z, 'o' )                         # plot original support points

plt.show()
```

Output (slightly rotated to match CAD):
[image]

**EDIT:**

A better approach (and one that looks more like your rhino3d CAD) is to treat the given points as the **P1 and P2 points** of the Bezier curves. P3 points are then chosen by averaging the P2 point of one segment with the P1 point of the next (and similarly for the P0 points). This ensures common tangency at the joined cubic Beziers. Note that, in this circumstance the curve doesn't necessarily go through any of the given points - they are all Bezier control points.

```
def smooth( xyzvals ):
    '''Turns list of coordinates (pairwise) into list of cubic Bezier control points'''
    N = len( xyzvals )
    result = []

    for i in range( 0, N, 2 ):                                       # set cubic Beziers s as P1 and P2
        p1 = np.array( xyzvals[i] )                                  # use original points as P1 and P2
        p2 = np.array( xyzvals[i+1] )

        im, ip = ( N + i - 1 ) % N, ( i + 2 ) % N                    # indices of adjacent points (cyclic)
        pm = np.array( xyzvals[im] )                                 
        p4 = np.array( xyzvals[ip] )
        p0 = 0.5 * ( pm + p1 )                                       # assign end points to ensure tangency
        p3 = 0.5 * ( p2 + p4 )

        result.append( [ p0, p1, p2, p3 ] )

    return result
```

This time the roller-coaster is a little smoother:
[image]

Comment: huge progress, its truly step forward, Thaks @lastchance . yes i extract exact points from cad software. I'm still just wondering. in that way that i learned, for finding 2 middle points of cubic Bezier curve (control points) we need to solve a linear equation system by Gaussian algorithm. in that way better that estimating? cheers

Comment: No, I didn't have to solve a linear system by gaussian elimination. I estimated tangents (from "forward" and "backward" points) and ended up with explicit expressions for the Bezier control points. The key function doing this in my code is smooth().

Comment: yea i saw that, interesting approach, thanks.

Comment: @pooriabt, I have edited my post to give (at the end) an alternative approach. Here, the given points are taken as the P1 and P2 points of the Beziers. It is then much easier to set P0 and P3 to get tangency.

Comment: yes truly this way gives smoother curve, I did not think this way about it.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the way your rhino3d CAD drew the curve.

Comment: i draw that curve in rhino only for extracting the points coordinates, as i said before, the goal was use them as p0 and p3 and get the p1 and p2 coordinates with Gaussian elimination. i still has no idea how to implement that algorithm to this code.